# C++ inheritance, can't access the inherited elements

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class SymbolNode {
    public:
        string name;
        Type type;
        int offset;
        SymbolNode(string name_, Type type_, int offset_): name(name_), type(type_), offset(offset_) {
        }
    };

class FuncNode : public SymbolNode {
    public:
        Type returnType;
        vector<Type> entries;
        FuncNode(string name_, Type type_, int offset_,Type returnType,vector<Type> entries):
                SymbolNode(name_,type_,offset_) ,returnType(returnType),entries(entries) {}
    };
```

So I have the inherited class FuncNode of the base class SymbolNode. And when I try to access the elements of  ***func*** I can't access all of them. 
I would like to add ***func*** to vector ***Symbols***. But also have the ability to access all the elements.

```
std::shared_ptr<SymbolNode> func= make_shared<FuncNode>("inc",FUNC,1,INT,entries);
vector<std::shared_ptr<SymbolNode>> Symbols;
```

Comment: "Can't access all of them" - can you expand on that a bit, please?

Comment: Can't access the returntype and entries

Answer (score 0):

Try **dynamic_cast** or **static_cast**

Comment: Where exactly I should put it?

Comment: Give me a minute, please, i must check, can't do it memory.

Comment: dynamic_cast only works when there's at least one virtual method in the class hierarchy.

Comment: auto f0 = Symbols[0].get();
    auto f = static_cast<FuncNode*> (f0);

Comment: I highly appreciate your comment, @selbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::shared_ptr<SymbolNode> func= make_shared<FuncNode>("inc",FUNC,1,INT,entries);
```

IN the above line, `func` is a (shared) pointer to the base class.  As such, it doesn't know what it's derived type this.  Hence, it can't access the members of `FuncNode`

You can express it as this:

```
std::shared_ptr<FuncNode> func= make_shared<FuncNode>("inc",FUNC,1,INT,entries);
```

Or do this:

```
std::shared_ptr<SymbolNode> symnode = make_shared<FuncNode>("inc",FUNC,1,INT,entries);

std::shared_ptr<FuncNode> func = static_pointer_cast<FuncNode>(symnode);
```